# Are there any updates for creating project templates in MSVS2022

Tags: visual-studio

I found few topics about problems with creating templates but I couldn't still create template myself. As a base for template I took files from exporting template for console application, I tried to change files and remake archive with no success (I also tried to clean Visual Studio cache in `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\`). I tried to copy template archive to different folders with no success. So, the only way for me is export template from existing project, but I cannot modify it. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide for adding new template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it often happens, the problem was with my inattention. Firstly you need a `.zip` extension, not a `.7z`, for template archive. Next, you should add to archive files themself, not a folder containing files.